# Menu global (generico) PHP

Tags: php, web, genericos

Es que tengo un codigo dfe una pagina en PHP y tiene muchas ventanas, y pues tiene un menu, pero no es generico, es que el menu se ve en la ventana 1 y pues bueno normal, pero ese mismo menu se tiene que ver en la ventana 2 y 3. asi que me toca escribir otra vez todas las lineas de codigo del menu, y son como 300 no tiene sentido... a eso sumarle que son 30 ventanas.

Asi que lo que quiero es crear 1 unico menu, y cada que haga una ventana consumirlo, con eso si le hago alguna modificacion no tener que hacercelo a las 30 ventanas si no a 1 solo archivo.

No se si me hice entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Usar `include` o `include_once` en php.

Pues una opción es crear un archivo `php` en donde copies todo el código de tu Navegación y en todos los demás archivos (también `php`), simplemente llamas
[`include_once '{archivo_con_navegacion.php}';`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

#### Ejemplo con `include_once`

layout.php

```php
<nav>
  ...
</nav>
```

dashboard.php:

```php
<?php include_once 'layout.php'; ?>
<div>
...
</div>
```

Esto mostrara todo html de tu `layout.php` en cualquier archivo en el que llames `<?php include_once 'layout.php'; ?>`

#### 2. Usar un "Template Engine"

Otra opción seria usar algún "Template Engine" como [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/)

Comment: Brutal!!!! eso era lo que necesitaba. Gracias